# Pull password.key file without rooting

Tags: security, password

Is there a way to access the `password.key` file without rooting the phone?

Is there a way of reading the chip without going through the Android security stuff to gain full access?

Comment: How old is the Android device? To my knowledge the `password.key` file is only relevant for old versions prior to Android 6. Afterwards "Gatekeeper" was introduced.

Comment: @Robert ok, so it's "gatekeeper.password.key" now?

Comment: Yes, but Gatekeeper on recent devices is a hardware security based protection which means manipulating that file will only end up in total data loss. If an Android phone has been rebooted it requires the PIN/password/pattern to decrypt the user data files. No matter what you do will change that as the PIN/password/pattern is required to build the encryption key.

Comment: @Robert just want the file to crack the password, if that is possible

Comment: Good luck, that would require to crack the Gatekeeper TEE environment to get the "hardware-backed secret key" and then reverse the stored HMAC-SHA256: https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/authentication/gatekeeper Both is impossible for common users.

Comment: @Robert OK, so it's impossible. Thanks for Infos mate:)